# Having trouble understanding the solution to this second-order nonlinear ordinary differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I used wolframalpha to solve this second order nonlinear ode of the form x''(t) = Ax'(t)^3 + Bx'(t)^2 + Cx'(t). The solution is here (https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%27%27%28t%29+%3D+Ax%27%28t%29%5E3+%2B+Bx%27%28t%29%5E2+%2B+Cx%27%28t%29). The part I am struggling to understand is the part of the solution where it says x -> (in red in the attached image). Could someone please explain that part to me? I would really appreciate some help!

[X Approaches Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y3Zov.png)

Comment: @Moo right, but in the context of the question how should I interpret that? What does it mean in terms of the solution?

Comment: Looks like in the context of the problem it means "the inverse of the function of x given in the parentheses, evaluated at ..." Since that inverse has no closed form, this is the best it can do.